# PHP Show data with my case

Tags: php, mysql

What I want to do is, show my self post and show friend post (if status_friend value=1).

This script has worked good for friend post, but I can't show my self post.
It likes a facebook/twitter, if I add someone to be a friend so friend post will show in my news feed. But now I can't show my self post.

Any idea ?

```
SELECT
messages.msg_id, 
messages.message, 
messages.date_post, 
messages.url, 
messages.username, 
user.username, 
user.full_name, 
user.status_friend

FROM 

messages, 
user 

WHERE 
message.username = user.username AND user.status_friend = '1'
order by msg_id desc
```

Comment: Is that your whole query? How do you select your own posts rather than selecting every single post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, this is what you need.

```
SELECT
messages.msg_id, 
messages.message, 
messages.date_post, 
messages.url, 
messages.username, 
user.username, 
user.full_name, 
user.status_friend

FROM 

messages, 
user 
WHERE 
message.username = user.username AND
(user.status_friend = '1' OR user.username = 'myusername')

order by msg_id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see both your own posts and the posts by your friends in results, you need a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    messages.msg_id,
    messages.message,
    messages.date_post,
    messages.url,
    messages.username,
    user.username,
    user.full_name,
    user.status_friend
FROM
    users
    JOIN
    messages
    ON
        messages.username = users.username
WHERE
    users.username = 'your_user_name'
    OR users.status_friend = '1'
ORDER BY
    msg_id DESC
```

I am not sure I understand your friending model fully though, post some details if that doesn't answer your question.